# I need a simple python Django login example using database credentials

Tags: django, django-login, django-postgresql, django-mysql

Could you please help me find an example of a simple login page where the users can be  authenticated  using user/password from a database postgres or mysql(I can change that afterwards from mysql to PG )?

I googled for almost 1 week but wasn't able to find  a django python example.
I actually found a Flask example - and: that is exactly what I need - but not using Flask - I need Django.

Here the flask example I found: [Flask_Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIiNYn0q1gs)

In this Flask example is - most important : login window  on the first place after starting of the web application, no TABs, no Navbar, no sidebar, no first click on a button "Login" and then login,  nothing really nothing except a white blank page with a little login window in the middle of the screen where you can put your user and password and if the credentials are correct in the database, then you will be redirected to a simple page containing whatever inside.
All that what I wrote here is exactly in that Flask example, but... I need a Django and no Flask.

There are so many professional people who are writing Django code examples... but there is nothing to find about so simple thing...

Can somebody give me an Django example, exactly that what is in the mentioned Flask link?

thank you and sorry for my bad english - I am from Austria
best

Comment: If you are after code examples, ChatGPT can do that, though you will likely have to fiddle  to get it working

Comment: The [`Authentication views`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) come shipped with django. Just setup a blank django project and include `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` to your URL-patterns as described in linked section. That should do the trick.

Comment: are you looking for something liek this? https://github.com/egorsmkv/simple-django-login-and-register

Comment: @Tarquinius: Thank you for that point... as I am a beginner in Django/Python - I have the next problem: "Using the URLconf defined in msgsolutions.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
accounts/
The empty path didn’t match any of these." What is here missing and where to put that what is missing? any simple code example would be very nice - my goal is to start a small/simple django app and have - at the start of the app - displayed a little window for entering a user/password an no other icons/navbars/etc. - any help is highly appreciated

Comment: [This tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/) might help you setting up the structure of your project. Then when it comes to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/#id3) section do as I said the comment before and include `django.contrib.auth.urls`. Then head to url "your-local-host/login/". I'd suggest going for the official django tutorial, youtube tutorials and maybe even chatgpt since your question is not in any way specific and too much to handle for a stackoverflow question.